# How to make a function point to another function (with overload)?

Tags: delphi

I have these 4 functions:

```
function ALmyfunctA(const Filename: AnsiString): Boolean;
function ALmyfunctW(const Filename: String): Boolean;
function ALmyfunct(const Filename: AnsiString): Boolean; overload;
function ALmyfunct(const Filename: String): Boolean; overload;
```

Is their an easy way to do something like this?

```
function ALmyfunct(const Filename: AnsiString): Boolean; = function  ALmyfunctA(const Filename: AnsiString): Boolean;
```

and

```
function ALmyfunct(const Filename: String): Boolean; = function  ALmyfunctA(const Filename: String): Boolean;
```

I could do it using `var`:

```
var ALmyfunct: function(const Filename: String): Boolean;
```

But it does not work with the `overload` :(

So, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
FUNCTION AlMyFunct(CONST FileName : STRING) : BOOLEAN; INLINE;
  BEGIN
    Result:=AlMyFunctA(FileName)
  END;
```

By declaring it INLINE you don't incur an additional call. The call is diverted directly to the A function without ever reaching the non-A version.

Comment: (Formally, the inline is a hint. The compiler might refuse to for very complex functions)

Answer (score 3):

You can not assign a function to another function. Although you can call a function from within another function.

But you definitely can assign overloaded functions to a function variable:

```
function ALmyfunctA(const Filename: AnsiString): Boolean;
begin
end;
function ALmyfunctW(const Filename: string): Boolean;
begin
end;
function ALmyfunct(const Filename: AnsiString): Boolean; overload;
begin
end;
function ALmyfunct(const Filename: string): Boolean; overload;
begin
end;

procedure Test;
var
  F1: function(const Filename: string): Boolean;
  F2: function(const Filename: AnsiString): Boolean;
begin
  // This works
  F1 := AlmyfunctW;
  F2 := AlmyfunctA;

  // This works Too
  F1 := Almyfunct;
  F2 := Almyfunct;
end;
```

Note: I recommend using types:

```
type
  TStringToBool = function(const Filename: string): Boolean;
  TAnsiStringToBool = function(const Filename: AnsiString): Boolean;

var
  F1: TStringToBool;
  F2: TAnsiStringToBool;
```

**Code tried in Delphi 10.4.**